# Why java compiler is not compiling code in sequence (top to bottom)?

Tags: java, android

```
String gst="123564";
int profile_status2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);

    fn();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Toast in onCreate method:  "+profile_status2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


private void fn() {
    setDataToDatabase tan = ServerConnection.doConnect();
    tan.profile_status(gst, new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ServerResponse response, Response response2) {
            profile_status2 = Integer.parseInt(response.msg);
            Toast.makeText(test2.this, "toast in method: " + profile_status2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

After building an application, i get results where first toast is from oncreate method which is meant to be visible after the toast of void success method.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the order of compilation. It's the order of *execution*.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the code inside `Callback<ServerResponse>()` runs asynchronous and that `Toast` is being called synchronous; You'd need a callback `interface`, which can be triggered when the request is complete, in order to show the `Toast`.

Answer (score 0):

Toast in success method is triggered when response is received. Obviously an asynchronous method needs some time to be called and receive any response (also errors); Toast in onCreate method doesn't need time to be displayed.